# React.js State changes drastically between console.log's without anything changing it (after it already updated itself properly)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Been working on a family recipe project for the coding class I'm currently in. This all takes place on my create Recipe page, the issue being I've run into a weird occurrence with State updating seemingly on it's own. I've got a state variable `numOfI` (number of ingredients) that holds an Array of components I've created on the page and several functions to add and remove my created components from the Array with state. This way a user can add and remove as many ingredients and eventually steps as necessary. Here's the RecipeNew page's code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { createRecipe } from '../services/recipeService';
import IngredientInput from '../componenets/IngredientInput';

export default function RecipeNew(props) {

    const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
        creator: '',
        access: '',
        name: '',
        ingredients: [{ amount: '', ingred: '' }],
        steps: []
    });

    const [numOfI, setNumOfI] = useState([<IngredientInput first='true' onChange={handleChange}
    key={0}/>]);
   

    const [numOfSteps, setNumOfSteps] = useState([]);

    console.log(numOfI);

    async function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(formState);


        createRecipe(formState);
        setFormState({
            creator: '',
            access: '',
            name: '',
            ingredients: [{ amount: '', ingred: '' }],
            steps: []
        });
        props.history.push('/home');

    }

    function handleChange(event) {
        console.log(event.target)
        setFormState({ ...formState, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    }


    function handleAdditionalIngredient() {

        const newArray = [];
        newArray.push(
            <IngredientInput pos={numOfI.length} key={numOfI.length} handleRemoveIngredient={handleRemoveIngredient}
                handleChange={handleChange}
                setNumOfI={setNumOfI} numOfI={numOfI} />)
        setNumOfI(prevArray => [...prevArray, ...newArray]);


        console.log('numOfI');
        console.log(numOfI);

    }

    function handleRemoveIngredient(pos) {

        const newArray = [];

        console.log('numOfI before removal');
        console.log(numOfI)
        console.log('Pos Removed')
        console.log(pos)
        console.log('---------------')

        // numOfI.forEach((ing, i) => {
        //     console.log('Ingred:')
        //     console.log(ing);
        //     console.log(' ');

        //     if(pos === i){
        //         return;
        //     } else{
        //         newArray.push(ing);
        //     }


        // });
        console.log('================')
        // console.log('New Array')
        // console.log(newArray)
        // setNumOfI([...newArray])
        console.log('Num Of I')
        console.log(numOfI)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className='ingred'>
                    <input type='text' name='name'
                        placeholder='Name' onChange={handleChange} />

                    {numOfI}

                    <button type="button" onClick={handleAdditionalIngredient}>+</button>
                </div>

                <div className='steps'>
                    <textarea cols="40" rows="5" type="" name='steps[]' placeholder={`Step ${numOfSteps + 1}`} />
                </div>
                <button>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And the code for the component I created (just in case):

```
export default function IngredientInput(props){
    const amount= `amount[${(props.pos)+1}]`
    const ingred= `ingredients[${(props.pos)+1}].ingred`

    const checkFirst = props.first === 'true' ? <></> : 
    <button onClick={() => props.handleRemoveIngredient(props.pos)} 
            type='button'>-</button>
       

    return(
        <div>
            <input type='text' name={amount} 
                onChange={props.handleChange} placeholder='#'/>

            <input type='text' name={ingred}
                onChange={props.handleChange} placeholder='Ingredient'/>

            {checkFirst}  
        </div>
    );
}
```

Adding items with `handleAdditionalIngredient` correctly adjusts the state, the update happens outside the function, since the console.log inside is too quick for the async nature of state but it does update properly.

The issue arises when I attempt to remove a item using `handleRemoveIngredient`. With all the code adjusting the state of numOfI commented out, somehow between the console.log just after my const [state] declarations and the first line of `handleRemoveIngredient` the state has completely changed. Example of the browser console below, but the other thing occuring is I'm pushing the + (`handleAdditionalIngredient`) button three times, then pressing the stripped - (`handleRemoveIngredient`) button once.

```
RecipeNew.js:57 numOfI
RecipeNew.js:58 [{…}]           //Inside the handleAdditonalIngredient
RecipeNew.js:22 (2) [{…}, {…}]   // In the main RecipeNew function
RecipeNew.js:57 numOfI
RecipeNew.js:58 (2) [{…}, {…}]
RecipeNew.js:22 (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
RecipeNew.js:57 numOfI
RecipeNew.js:58 (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
RecipeNew.js:22 (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]   
RecipeNew.js:66 numOfI before removal
RecipeNew.js:67 (2) [{…}, {…}]
```

As you can see the state drastically changes from 4 elements in the array to 2 without anything else effecting the state, the only lines being calling numOfI are console.log()'s.

What am I doing wrong? Or what don't I know that would cause this to happen? I've been googling for the past two days without any success, so any insight / assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: could you provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and clarify what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The first obvious immedaite thing wrong with this is that you are storing react nodes in your state variable

```
const [numOfI, setNumOfI] = useState([<IngredientInput first='true' onChange={handleChange}
    key={0}/>]);
```

Where as further on down you are attempting to store a different type

```
setNumOfI([...newArray])
```

ostensibly a number.

I would look first at the type for this state variable, you probably are trying to store a number, and then render by iterating through your loop.

You should consider rethinking your Ingredient data structure, perhaps giving it an `id` field, and store only the ingredient data in your state.